# Start application (GUI) upon mount of any USB devices

Tags: usb, mount, scripts, udev, automation

I am running Ubuntu-gnome 16.04 LTS 4.4.0-62-generic.

I would like to do following: Run either ...

- (a) an application (**GUI**) [/path/to/my_app.desktop]
- or (b) an **interactive** script in a terminal [e.g.: $ gnome-terminal -x /path/to/script.sh]

... whenever a mount of **any** (USB) device is recognized.

The execution on the user's X-server seems mandatory since varying user input is required in response to the running application/script; it can not simply run in the background.

For the last 2 days I have done extensive research and experimented with both, *udev-rules* and *systemd.services*. My re-occurring problem tough is, that either of the latter approaches *requires X-authentification*. Altough there sure are (convoluted) ways to make the authentification happen, I do not like the idea to *breach the innate system security* by exporting the $XAUTHORITY variables from root to the user's session...

I suppose there should be an alternative way to make the following happening:

1. detect when/if a new (USB) device was mounted
2. start an application/script(in terminal) with USER privileges on user desktop (i.e. user's Xsession?)
3. (optional: pass the devicename on as a variable)

(creation of mount-specific .config files?;  org.gnome.desktop.media-handling?; autostart-script observing /home/$USERNAME/media .mounts?; editing /etc/fstab; ...?)

Any hints would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi brunuser, I was pretty sure I answered a question like this before, but it turned out to be a look-alike :). Please mention if all is clear (or not).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Old answer, new answer further below)

---

#### Run a script or command to run whenever a usb drive gets connected

If, for whatever reasons, you do not want to use `udev` rules or anything more complicated, then use the script below.

Simply running the script, with your command to run as argument, will do the job.

#### The script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time
import sys

cmd = " ".join(sys.argv[1:])

def get_mountedlist():
    return [(item.split()[0].replace("├─", "").replace("└─", ""),
             item[item.find("/"):]) for item in subprocess.check_output(
            ["/bin/bash", "-c", "lsblk"]).decode("utf-8").split("\n") if "/" in item]

def identify(disk):
    command = "find /dev/disk -ls | grep /"+disk
    return "usb" in subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", command]).decode("utf-8")

mounted1 = get_mountedlist()
while True:
    time.sleep(4)
    mounted2 = get_mountedlist()
    if [d for d in mounted2 if all([not d in mounted1, d != "/", identify(d[0]) == True])]:
        subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd])
    mounted1 = mounted2
```

#### To use

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `run_usbactions.py`
2. Test- run the script by (e.g.) the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/run_usbactions.py <command_to_run> <optional_args>
   ```

   In my test, I used e.g.:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/run_usbactions.py gedit file
   ```

   to open `file` with gedit once a usb drive is connected.
3. If all works fine, add it to Startup Applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add. Add the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/run_usbactions.py <command_to_run> <optional_args>
   ```

#### Explanation

- Once per four seconds, in the function `get_mountedlist()`, the script reads the output of `lsblk`.
- In case *additional* partitions or devices are mounted, the output of (e.g.) the command:

  ```
  find /dev/disk -ls | grep sdc1
  ```

  will include the string `usb`, and identify the mounted drive as a usb drive. 
  Looking at it now, I very well could replace it by a more "pythonic" way of doing it, instead of a system call, but since I copied it from an older script, I didn't (yet).
- subsequently, *if* the new drive is a usb, the command (+ possible args), as set in `" ".join(sys.argv[1:])` is run.

---

### EDIT

(December 29, 2017)

#### Using pyudev

Since I "met" pyudev, I thought I should share the major simplification and clearer operation it brings. A simple script to perform any action on inserting a usb device then becomes:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pyudev
import subprocess
import sys

cmd = " ".join(sys.argv[1:])

monitor = pyudev.Monitor.from_netlink(pyudev.Context())
monitor.filter_by('block')

for device in iter(monitor.poll, None):
    if all([
        device['ACTION'] == "add", 'ID_FS_TYPE' in device,
        device['ID_USB_DRIVER'] == "usb-storage",
        ]):
        print("added", device.get('ID_FS_LABEL'))
        subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd])
```

#### Usage

Make sure `pyudev` is installed:

```
sudo apt install python3-pyudev
```

Further instructions are exactly similar.

Comment: thanks for Your fast reply. As stated in my OQ, udev rules simply do not start any application on the user interface.... Since I am a programming newbie - but willing to learn - let me try to ask a question regarding your script: `def identify(disk):
    command = "find /dev/disk -ls | grep /"+disk
    return "usb" in subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", command]).decode("utf-8")` defines the command `identify(disk)` by returning any mount events containing the string "usb" in `find /dev/disk -ls` output.: Why is in `command=...+disk` the addition of the latter required?

Comment: @brunuser I added an explanation. Please mention if all is clear (or not).

Comment: Vljim , thanks again. Yeah, I was wondering especially about the `command = "find /dev/disk -ls | grep /"*+disk*` expression, i.e. the `+disk` operator to the grep `/` pattern, but I got it now; in my case the line would be `command = "find /dev/disk -ls | grep /sdb`. If I might be allowed to ask one further (stupid) question: `if [d for d in mounted2 if all([not d in mounted1, d != "/", identify(d[0]) == True])]:` what does the `identify(d[0]) == True` condition mean/test? (I think I got the rest, but the latter is enigmatic to me.)

Comment: @brunuser please ask! The function `identify(device)` returns `True` if the device is a usb device, hence `identify(d[0]) == True` . One more thing: (only) *if* the answer solved your question, would you be so kind to accept the answer (tick the big "V" below the up/down arrows on the left). It is the appropriate way to indicate the answer worked for you.

Comment: @ Vlijm. Right now I am trying to reverse-engineer Your python script as a bash version (practical experience helps me to better understand). Altough not having excessively tested Your script, I highly appreciate Your response and will therefore mark it as answered for now. :)